# summernote dropdown-menu overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, summernote

I have a 2 columns layout inside 2 divs with different margins set, on the left column I have a bootstrap datetimepicker and summernote.

As you can see the datetimepicker dialog overflows outside the internal div, how can I achieve the same with summernote's dropdowns? Is it possible?

Here's my playground with the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/SycoLTH/2j0ykbgf/

```
<style>
form {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#out-container {
  background-color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

#in-container {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 80%;
  max-width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 3%;
}

#column-left,
#column-right {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker({
  showClear: true,
  showTodayButton: true
});

$(".summernote").summernote({
  theme: "simplex",
  disableDragAndDrop: true,
  shortcuts: false,
  toolbar: [
    ["style", ["bold", "italic", "underline", "clear"]],
    ["misc", ["undo", "redo"]],
    ["font", ["strikethrough", "superscript", "subscript"]],
    ["fontsize", ["fontsize"]],
    ["color", ["color"]],
    ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]],
    ["insert", ["picture", "link", "video", "table", "hr"]],
    ["height", ["height"]]
  ]
});
</script>

<div id="out-container">
  <div id="in-container">
    <form>
      <div id="column-left" class="pull-left">
        Some text
        <br> Some text
        <br> Some text
        <br> Some text
        <br> Some text
        <br> Some text
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="column-right" class="pull-left">
        Date:
        <br>
        <input type="text" class="datetimepicker form-control" />
        <br>
        <br> Text:
        <br>
        <textarea class="summernote"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`position: absolute` objects are cropped by the bound of its nearest `position: relative` object. In this case, the easiest way to show summernote popovers over the boundary, try to set the right column as below.

```
#column-right {
  overflow:visible;
}
```

Ref: http://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent

Comment: I'm not against overflow visible, but how can I make the right page scroll inside his container then?
Also, any idea why the data picker works as expected? That's also position absolute.

Comment: @Syco As I mentioned above, it's up to their parents. If you set `position: relative` on `#column-right`, then it will not display over the column.